# For spirit::x3, what is the right way to deal with unknown symbols?

Tags: boost-spirit-x3

A newbie for x3... The code is adapted from the roman.cpp in the x3 tutorial. Suppose I have a symbol table like below:

```
struct car_models_ : x3::symbols<char, unsigned>
{
    car_models_()
    {
        add
            ("sedan", 1)
            ("compact", 2)
            ("suv", 3)
        ;
    }
} car_models;
```

Then parse,

```
char const *first = "Model: sedan";
char const *last = first + std::strlen(first);
parse(first, last, "Model: " >> car_models[action()]);
```

If there is new model not listed in the symbol table, what would be the right way to handle it? Is there a way to add a wildcard as the last entry in the symbol table, and then somehow pass an unknown model to action (e.g., number "0" in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it inside the symbol table itself. One possibility is:

```cpp
auto ext_car_models = car_models | (x3::omit[*x3::lower] >> attr(0))
```

Then to parse:

```
parse(first, last, "Model: " >> ext_car_models[action()]);
```

Ignoring the attribute for a moment, your symbol table is effectively syntactic sugar for:

```
x3::string("sedan") | "compact" | "suv"
```

So, handling an unknown string in that position would need to be handled the same way. You will need to define a parser that defines what a model string looks like. Possibly `*x3::lower`